# How can I display the edges between vertices in IBM Graph?

Tags: ibm-cloud, graph-databases, ibm-graph

I am able to successfully build vertices in IBM Graph, but when I execute query, output doesn't show the edges between vertices. I am running following code:

```
def v1 = graph.addVertex("name", "Darshit", label, "Inventorymanager","zip","95112"); 
def v2 = graph.addVertex("name", "Vikas", label, "Vendor","zip","95112"); 
def v3 = graph.addVertex("name", "Sidharth", label, "Vendor","zip","95112"); 
def v4 = graph.addVertex("name", "iPhone7", label, "Item","price",750,"quantity",10); 
def v5 = graph.addVertex("name", "chair", label, "Item","price",20,"quantity",15); 
def v6 = graph.addVertex("name", "laptop", label, "Item","price",800,"quantity",3);  
v1.addEdge("ordered_to", v2); 
v1.addEdge("ordered_to", v3); 
v2.addEdge("has", v4); 
v3.addEdge("has", v5); 
v2.addEdge("has", v6); 
v3.addEdge("has", v6);    
def g = graph.traversal(); 
g.V().has("name", "Darshit").out("ordered_to").has("name", "Vikas").path();
```

Comment: Can you paste the output your getting from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
g.V().has("name", "Darshit").outE("ordered_to").inV().has("name", "Vikas").path();
```

That'll get you the edges as well